# sqlalchemy postgres: check constraint across tables

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a schema for football match orientated data. I have a `matches` table which contains match related info, but crucially:

- id
- team_one_id
- team_two_id

I also have a `teams` and `players` table.

I then also have a `squadmembers` table where i have the following columns:

- id
- match_id
- team_id
- player_id

where across {`match_id`, `team_id`, `player_id`} i have applied a unique constraint with each of them FK-ing to their respective tables (`match_id` to `matches.id`, `team_id` to `teams.id` etc)

My problem is this - I'd like to also at the database level apply the constraint that i cannot create a `squadmembers` entry unless we have {`squadmembers.match_id`, `squadmembers.team_id`} in either of:

- {`matches.id`, `matches.team_one_id`}
- {`matches.id`, `matches.team_two_id`}

**In other words - you can't create a squadmember in team that wasn't in the match.** The problem here is coming from the fact I can't just place a composite FK constraint on {`squadmembers.match_id`, `squadmembers.team_id`} vs {`matches.id`, `matches.team_id`} but instead need something along the lines of an `or` statement vs `team_one_id` & `team_two_id`.

Is this achievable?

SQLAlchemy code below for minimum reproduce-able example:

```
import datetime as dt
from typing import Optional
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey, String, UniqueConstraint, CheckConstraint
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column, relationship

class TeamModel(DeclarativeBase):
    """Teams model"""

    __tablename__ = "teams"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "core"}

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column("id", primary_key=True, index=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column("name", String(255))
 
class PlayerModel(DeclarativeBase):
    """Players model"""

    __tablename__ = "players"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "core"}

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column("id", primary_key=True, index=True)
    name: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column("name", String(255))

class MatchModel(DeclarativeBase):
    """Matches model"""

    __tablename__ = "matches"
    __table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint("match_date", "team_one_id", "team_two_id", name="date_teams_uc"),
        CheckConstraint("team_one_id <> team_two_id"),
        {"schema": "core"},
    )

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column("id", primary_key=True, index=True, sort_order=-3)
    match_date: Mapped[dt.date] = mapped_column("match_date", sort_order=-2)
    team_one_id: Mapped[Optional[int]] = mapped_column("team_one_id", ForeignKey("core.teams.id", name="matches_team_one_fk"))
    team_two_id: Mapped[Optional[int]] = mapped_column("team_two_id", ForeignKey("core.teams.id", name="matches_team_two_fk"))

    team_one = relationship(TeamModel, foreign_keys=[team_one_id])
    team_two = relationship(TeamModel, foreign_keys=[team_two_id])

class SquadMemberModel(DeclarativeBase):
"""SquadMembers model"""

    __tablename__ = "squadmembers"
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint("match_id", "team_id", "player_id", name="match_team_shirtnumber_uc"), {"schema": "core"})
    
    id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column("id", String(255), primary_key=True, index=True)
    match_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column("match_id", ForeignKey("core.matches.id", name="squadmembers_match_fk"))
    team_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column("team_id", ForeignKey("core.teams.id", name="squadmembers_team_fk"))
    player_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column("player_id", ForeignKey("core.players.id", name="squadmembers_player_fk"))
    
    # define our relationships
    match = relationship(MatchModel)
    player = relationship(PlayerModel)
    team = relationship(TeamModel)
```